# Latex and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, latex, anaconda

I am generating plots in Python (via Jupyter notebook, everything installed using anaconda) using matplotlib and would like to use latex. Please find the code and the error below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

# setting up plot params
font = {'family':'Arial','size':40}
mpl.rc('font',**font) 
mpl.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':40})
mpl.rc('text',usetex=True)

mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\boldmath']
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.unicode'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True 

mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 2.75
mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0,15.0)
mpl.rcParams['savefig.bbox'] = 'tight'

plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lws = 5 
x = np.linspace(-6.28,6.28,100)
ax.plot(x,np.sin(x),'-',lw=lws,c='r')
plt.legend(loc=1,fontsize=30)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=10)
plt.savefig('a.png')
plt.show()
```

### And this give, the following error (mostly with Latex I guess),

```
         ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
         <ipython-input-45-85e3ff3aacbc> in <module>()
               6 plt.legend(loc=1,fontsize=30)
               7 plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=10)
         ----> 8 plt.savefig('a.png')
               9 plt.show()

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in savefig(*args, **kwargs)
             686 def savefig(*args, **kwargs):
             687     fig = gcf()
         --> 688     res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
             689     fig.canvas.draw_idle()   # need this if 'transparent=True' to reset colors
             690     return res

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in savefig(self, *args, **kwargs)
            1563             self.set_frameon(frameon)
            1564 
         -> 1565         self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
            1566 
            1567         if frameon:

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
            2178                     orientation=orientation,
            2179                     dryrun=True,
         -> 2180                     **kwargs)
            2181                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
            2182                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
             525 
             526     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
         --> 527         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
             528         renderer = self.get_renderer()
             529         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in draw(self)
             472 
             473         try:
         --> 474             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
             475         finally:
             476             RendererAgg.lock.release()

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
              60         before(artist, renderer)
         ---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              62         after(artist, renderer)
              63 

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
            1157         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
            1158         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
         -> 1159             func(*args)
            1160 
            1161         renderer.close_group('figure')

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
              60         before(artist, renderer)
         ---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              62         after(artist, renderer)
              63 

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
            2322 
            2323         for zorder, a in dsu:
         -> 2324             a.draw(renderer)
            2325 
            2326         renderer.close_group('axes')

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
              60         before(artist, renderer)
         ---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              62         after(artist, renderer)
              63 

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
            1106         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
            1107         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
         -> 1108                                                                 renderer)
            1109 
            1110         for tick in ticks_to_draw:

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
            1056         for tick in ticks:
            1057             if tick.label1On and tick.label1.get_visible():
         -> 1058                 extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
            1059                 ticklabelBoxes.append(extent)
            1060             if tick.label2On and tick.label2.get_visible():

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
             959             raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
             960 
         --> 961         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
             962         x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
             963         x, y = self.get_transform().transform_point((x, y))

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in _get_layout(self, renderer)
             350         tmp, lp_h, lp_bl = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent('lp',
             351                                                          self._fontproperties,
         --> 352                                                          ismath=False)
             353         offsety = (lp_h - lp_bl) * self._linespacing
             354 

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
             227             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
             228             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(s, fontsize,
         --> 229                                                                renderer=self)
             230             return w, h, d
             231 

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
             673         else:
             674             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
         --> 675             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
             676             dvi = dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction)
             677             try:

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
             420                      'string:\n%s\nHere is the full report generated by '
             421                      'LaTeX: \n\n' % repr(tex.encode('unicode_escape')) +
         --> 422                      report))
             423             else:
             424                 mpl.verbose.report(report, 'debug')

         RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
         'lp'
         Here is the full report generated by LaTeX: 

         No latex error report available.

         <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f8e49a49b10>

         ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
             305                 pass
             306             else:
         --> 307                 return printer(obj)
             308             # Finally look for special method names
             309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in <lambda>(fig)
             225 
             226     if 'png' in formats:
         --> 227         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
             228     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
             229         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
             117 
             118     bytes_io = BytesIO()
         --> 119     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
             120     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
             121     if fmt == 'svg':

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
            2178                     orientation=orientation,
            2179                     dryrun=True,
         -> 2180                     **kwargs)
            2181                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
            2182                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
             525 
             526     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
         --> 527         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
             528         renderer = self.get_renderer()
             529         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in draw(self)
             472 
             473         try:
         --> 474             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
             475         finally:
             476             RendererAgg.lock.release()

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
              60         before(artist, renderer)
         ---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              62         after(artist, renderer)
              63 

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
            1157         dsu.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
            1158         for zorder, a, func, args in dsu:
         -> 1159             func(*args)
            1160 
            1161         renderer.close_group('figure')

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
              60         before(artist, renderer)
         ---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              62         after(artist, renderer)
              63 

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
            2322 
            2323         for zorder, a in dsu:
         -> 2324             a.draw(renderer)
            2325 
            2326         renderer.close_group('axes')

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              59     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
              60         before(artist, renderer)
         ---> 61         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
              62         after(artist, renderer)
              63 

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
            1106         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
            1107         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
         -> 1108                                                                 renderer)
            1109 
            1110         for tick in ticks_to_draw:

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
            1056         for tick in ticks:
            1057             if tick.label1On and tick.label1.get_visible():
         -> 1058                 extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
            1059                 ticklabelBoxes.append(extent)
            1060             if tick.label2On and tick.label2.get_visible():

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
             959             raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
             960 
         --> 961         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
             962         x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
             963         x, y = self.get_transform().transform_point((x, y))

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in _get_layout(self, renderer)
             350         tmp, lp_h, lp_bl = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent('lp',
             351                                                          self._fontproperties,
         --> 352                                                          ismath=False)
             353         offsety = (lp_h - lp_bl) * self._linespacing
             354 

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
             227             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
             228             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(s, fontsize,
         --> 229                                                                renderer=self)
             230             return w, h, d
             231 

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
             673         else:
             674             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
         --> 675             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
             676             dvi = dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction)
             677             try:

         /data/b4004487/libs/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.pyc in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
             420                      'string:\n%s\nHere is the full report generated by '
             421                      'LaTeX: \n\n' % repr(tex.encode('unicode_escape')) +
         --> 422                      report))
             423             else:
             424                 mpl.verbose.report(report, 'debug')

         RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
         'lp'
         Here is the full report generated by LaTeX: 

         No latex error report available.

            <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f8e4a38c190>
```

Comment: The code run in my computer. Using Jupyter Notebook, Installed via Anaconda, but Python 3.

Comment: @Lucas: Unfortunately, mine is Python 2.7. Somehow, many things are installed around it. I actually don;t want to go to Python 3 for now but is there is a easy to to just change all dependencies to Python 3 using anaconda ?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean with: "change all dependencies to Python 3 ". One easy solution is install miniconda3 (is like anaconda but only the install conda and python3) and with conda install matplotlib. That will surely work. The error looks pretty ugly : (

Comment: You don't need to create two figures here (just delete `plt.figure()`) and there is no legend entry (label the line or delete `plt.legend()`). Appart from that, the code runs fine for me as well under python 2.7, matplotlib 2.0, miktex 2.9. It could be that the problem is rather on the side of your latex installation than on matplotlib's side. Does the [standard latex example](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) run for you?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Yes, the standard examples runs.

Comment: I think the way to go would then be to stepwise transform the running code into your example case to find out which command is causing the trouble. It may turn out that you thereby find a workaround or you can report back and ask more specifically about the exact problem.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: It works actually, as it is. I restarted everything and it works. Still don't know the problem though.